# [python-pika][pika] chu?

Tags: support, tag-synonym-process

Suggested synonyms: [python-pika](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-pika) and [pika](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pika).

I would suggest it myself, but I don't have a score of 5 in any tag.

They have identical description.

Comment: Does [pika] contain any non-Python related questions? Is there any risk of ambiguity in dropping the [python-*] prefix?

Comment: @CodyGray [Doesn't seem like it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pika%20not%20python%20not%20rabbitmq?mode=all); all questions seem to relate to the Python RabbitMQ library.